# How can one make files in an Azure DevOps repository publicly accessible?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is it possible to get a raw link to a file or path that is hosted in our Azure DevOps repository; like we can share on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at present time. VSTS is intended to be a private code repository for teams, not public.

You can always push your repos to GitHub as well as VSTS if you want to provide public code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible if your project is [defined as public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/about-public-projects?view=azure-devops); the API that allows one to do this is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

An example from one of my public repos: `https://dev.azure.com/ByteTerrace/CSharp/_apis/git/repositories/ByteTerrace.Maths.BitwiseHelpers/Items?path=%2FProject%2FBitwiseHelpers.cs&recursionLevel=0&versionDescriptor.version=master&versionDescriptor.versionOptions=0&versionDescriptor.versionType=0&includeContent=true&resolveLfs=true`

Finally, here is the parameterized version; for convenience: `https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepositoryName}/Items?path={PathToFile}&recursionLevel=0&versionDescriptor.version=master&versionDescriptor.versionOptions=0&versionDescriptor.versionType=0&includeContent=true&resolveLfs=true`

Comment: As of today, more than a year later than this answer, you need to set the entire Azure DevOps project public. If you are looking to make just a repository or a file public and keep everything else hidden, it is impossible.